# Hang and speed issue

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, ram, memory-usage, memory-leak

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with following details

Processor Intel® Core™ i5-4460 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4

GNOME: 3.28.1

Disk: 422.6 GB

Memory 3.8 GB

when i used `free -m`

```
               total       used        free       shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3842        1293         136         382        2412        1891
Swap:          2047           0        2047
```

I don't know where is my memory consume

Thanks

Comment: You only have 3.8GB of RAM, and you currently have 1891 MB (~1.9GB) of RAM still available for use (see the "Available" column's value).  https://www.linuxatemyram.com/ may be something you want to read.  What's your basis that your speed/hang issue is RAM based?

Comment: Memory consumption is  probably normal. Look at `head -5 /proc/meminfo` and you will see more details.

Comment: that time only a browser open and many time its hang and need to restart s according to its normal with 3.8GB I need to add ram in system

Comment: I remember once web extensions were consuming 6 GB RAM in my system which has 8 GB total RAM.

Comment: would your web browser happen to be Chrome, or Chromium, or some other Chrome based browser? Those can consume huuuuge amounts of memory as Kulfy noted above. Please make sure to disable all those web browser extensions until this problem is solved. More RAM would be your friend. If you absolutely, positively, cannot fit more RAM into your PC, look at zram http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/zramctl.8.html